# What is the server prefix for API call in mailchimp.com?

Tags: node.js, api, backend, mailchimp

```js
mailchimp.setConfig({
  apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
  server: "YOUR_SERVER_PREFIX",
});
```

Answer (score 6):

From [the documentation](https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/guides/quick-start/#make-your-first-api-call):

To find the value for the server parameter used in `mailchimp.setConfig`, log into your Mailchimp account and look at the URL in your browser. You’ll see something like "https://us19.admin.mailchimp.com/"; the `us19` part is the server prefix. Note that your specific value may be different.

Answer (score 3):

The server prefix is nothing but the starting part of the endpoint URL. For example, if you are using MailChimp API, you can check your server prefix by clicking this url: https://us19.admin.mailchimp.com/.

The server prefix will change to your server prefix automatically. For me it is `us18`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other comments, it's also the last digits of your API KEY.

Comment: Precisely. I never understood why the library just don't get it from the API key directly. At least by default. I am sure there is a reason but it feels tedious.